# How to get specific info inside class in BeatfiulSoup, Python

Tags: python

Okey so, this is code from website which im working about scrapping this.
[image: Text]

And this is my python code to scrap info but i get stuck after getting to div class with id=html4. It's showing me this class, but i don't have idea what to do, to go to classes inside this, i wanna get into these three classes

[image: Text]
And get from this <a href links

**CODE**

```
@client.command()
async def request(ctx,arg):
    await ctx.send("Passing ur request"+ ' ' + arg + ' ' + "standby")
    url1 = url + arg
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')

    for link in soup.find_all('div',attrs={'id':'content-section-2'}):
        try:
            s = link.find_all('div',attrs={'id':'HTML4'})
            content = str(s)
            print(content)
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

Comment: Have you tried `attrs={'class': 'item'}`?

Comment: @gvee Tried it. Giving me null response.

Comment: Consider using the [`recursive`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#recursive) argument of `find_all`. Note that your `.item`s are not _direct descendants_ (grandchildren in this case) of the `#HTML4` element.

Comment: @gvee Okey i just missed that items of #html aren't childrens of this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: [the documentation for `BeautifulSoup`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is fab!

[The `find_all()` method](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#find-all) that you're using contains a few useful hints to find what you need.

On to solving the problem at hand...

The `<div class="shad item item-0...` you're hunting for is **not a *direct descendant*** of the `#HTML4` element, meaning that just searching for `attrs={"class": "item"}` (or `_class="item"}` [see docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#searching-by-css-class)) does not work.

This is because the `find_all()` method, by default, only searches *direct children* of the `BeautifulSoup` object.

Luckily there's a [`recursive` keyword argument](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#recursive) that you can use:

```py
soup.find_all("div", _class="item", recursive=True)
```

That ought to do it!